# How does the Tomcat container calls service() method?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

How does the Tomcat container calls `service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)` method?
Where can I look for implementation of this call?
How can I see how this `req` and `res` objects (that passed to service() method) are  created?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/tomcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the [Tomcat Architecture](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/architecture/requestProcess.html) page is in TODO status, there is at least a link to the [UML sequence diagram](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/architecture/requestProcess/request-process.png) of the request processing. Combining with Tomcat's source code, it is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know it, first clone apache tomcat source code

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/tomcat.git
```

Then inside the cloned repository, launch this command to search where it is invoked `service` method:

```
grep -H -n -r "\.service(" --include=*.java
```

You will find a short file list:

```
java/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.java:107:     * in this PageContext until the return from the current Servlet.service()
java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java:3128:            //       that set towards the start of CoyoyeAdapter.service()
java/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationFilterChain.java:231:                servlet.service(request, response);
java/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.java:411:            super.service(req, resp);
java/org/apache/catalina/servlets/WebdavServlet.java:349:            super.service(req, resp);
java/org/apache/coyote/ajp/AjpProcessor.java:403:                    getAdapter().service(request, response);
java/org/apache/coyote/AsyncStateMachine.java:41: *                    been called during a single Servlet.service() method. The
java/org/apache/coyote/AsyncStateMachine.java:58: *                    been called during a single Servlet.service() method. The
java/org/apache/coyote/http11/Http11Processor.java:498:                    getAdapter().service(request, response);
java/org/apache/coyote/http2/StreamProcessor.java:257:            adapter.service(request, response);
java/org/apache/jasper/Constants.java:41:     * HttpJspBase.service(). This is where most of the code generated
java/org/apache/jasper/servlet/JspServlet.java:385:            wrapper.service(request, response, precompile);
java/org/apache/jasper/servlet/JspServletWrapper.java:440:                   servlet.service(request, response);
java/org/apache/jasper/servlet/JspServletWrapper.java:443:                servlet.service(request, response);
```

The most intresting one is `java/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationFilterChain.java`. You wil find more coincidences, but much of them are because there is another interface into Tomcat source code that has a very similar method `java/org/apache/coyote/Adapter.java` ignore it.

Once you get `java/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationFilterChain.java`, you can edit, got to line 231 and see where the service method is called.

However, both `req` and `res` objects are not created in that place. Finding how those are created seems to be a bit more complex and requires more time.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet lifecycle is controlled by the underlying container. Once the servlet has been initialized and there is a request, Tomcat will call the servlet's service method to process the request. 
Service method will delegate request to your Servlet class where you can get access to req and res objects in doGet or doPost methods.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
}
```

**Update :** 
 1. Upon request from the client, Container creates two objects : HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.
 2. Based on the request, Container will find correct Servlet (as per URL mapping), creates new thread for that particular request(one-to-one mapping - new thread for each request) and calls Servlet's service method, passing in created HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects as arguments.
 3. Based on request method (GET or POST) service() method will call doGet() or doPost() method in Servlet, again passing the same HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects as arguments.

Those are Servlet specifications in a nutshell. How does Tomcat act exactly is implementation specific, it is not controlled by specification. If you need to know how exactly it is implemented in Tomcat, you might check it's source code.

Comment: I understand, but how exactly the service() is called?
How are the objects that are sent to this service method are created?
Like if the tomcat code this 
   `ServletRequest request = new ServletRequest();    
ServletResponse responce = new ServletResponse();
request.doStuff():
responce.doStuff():
service(request, responce)
`